# Dojo Toolkit offline application

Tags: layout, dojo, widget, nested, offline

I have been integrating a standard border container (Nested Layout Widgets) from this site
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html which worked quite well.
The problem is that I want to use this application offline but didn't find a way to do so. I mean why do I have to be online to use it anyway?

Can you help here? Are there any files that are not stored locally that I have to link across the project? Or is it just not possible to use it offline?
Also, what about the dojo offline project anyway? Th last status is from 2007?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Best
TTP

Comment: I just found a way to use it offline: I downloaded the newest distribution of dojo and added the following code to my html file: `code`<script type="text/javascript"> var djConfig = { baseScriptUri : "html/js/dojo/", parseOnLoad : true }; </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="html/js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`code` which did the trick. Just one question: When I open the html file with Firefox I get an error message: There was a problem sending the command to the program; though the application works. In IE it works without error message...

Answer (score 0):

You should [look at the HTML5 application cache](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) for offline applications.  dojox.offline is pretty much abandoned given the newer browser technology.